# BackstopJS: Inject Javascript

Tags: backstop.js

I have a web app that is being embedded in a hybrid mobile app. The app injects some javascript which in turn adds some CSS. I want to add some tests that make sure changes to the web app do not break the mobile app.

My goal at the moment is to inject some CSS into the page before BackstopJS runs the tests.

I noticed that I can hide and remove elements using `hideSelectors` and `removeSelectors` but is there a way to inject some arbitrary CSS?

Answer (score 1):

The script at `capture/casper_scripts/onReady.js` runs in the web app. This is defined in **backstop.json** under:

```
"scenarios": [
  {
      …
      "onReadyScript": "onReady.js"
```